# Outlook 365 OAuth 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to send an email via smtp.live.com using an OAuth token generated via https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/… but I'm receiving the following error:

```
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

I can make it work by obtaining an auth token via https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf (a legacy API) but that only works for free Microsoft accounts (I need to support business/Outlook365 accounts too).

The fact I can make it work using that legacy endpoint seems to validate that:

- The server supports `XOAUTH2` (which I also validated via Telnet `EHLO`)
- That the encoding is correct (I'm using [this process](https://github.com/andris9/xoauth2/blob/master/src/xoauth2.js#L178))
- That I'm meant to pass the full access token via `XOAUTH2` and not something odd like pass it in via `LOGIN`, or decode the JWT and pass in some component etc.

The access token seems valid (it works for other calls, including sending an email via the Graph API).

I've requested the following scopes:

```
[
  'offline_access', 'User.Read', 'MailboxSettings.ReadWrite',
  'Mail.Send', 'Mail.ReadWrite', 'Mail.Read', 'Mail.ReadBasic', 'Contacts.ReadWrite',
  'Mail.Read.Shared', 'Mail.ReadWrite.Shared', 'Mail.Send.Shared', 'MailboxSettings.Read',
  'profile', 'openid', 'email', 'Calendars.ReadWrite',
  'EAS.AccessAsUser.All', 'EWS.AccessAsUser.All',
];
```

For the legacy token (the one which works), the scopes are different:

```
[
  'wl.emails', 'wl.offline_access', 'wl.imap'
];
```

(I've tried including these scopes when requesting the v2 token too, but it's invalid).

Other things I've tried:

- Using smtp.office365.com instead of smtp.live.com
- Obtaining fresh access tokens
- Ensuring app settings/permissions are configured correctly, as per [this article](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/sdk/?ct=object_oauth_live)
- [Enable Exchange SMTP Auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/enable-or-disable-modern-authentication-in-exchange-online)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I send SMTP email through Office365 shared mailbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59735368/can-i-send-smtp-email-through-office365-shared-mailbox)

Comment: First always make 100% sure your credentials are correct. Had this issue today, searched for many solutions, but it was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office 365 SMTP servers do not support OAuth authentication as of this time.

Comment: It seems that Office 365 SMTP support OAuth at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 SMTP servers is supporting OAuth authentication only through Code Authorization Flow not with the other mechanisms like Client Credentials flow e.t.c