# 'Authentication Unsuccessful' When Trying To Send Email Through Django

Tags: django, outlook, smtp, django-email

I've been trying to send emails using my Outlook email through Django but have been getting a variety of error messages, including

```
(535, b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [SYBPR01CA0102.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com]')
```

Apparently I need to allow SMTP AUTH, but cannot find how to do this as I am using Outlook in my browser and don't have it downloaded (it keeps requesting I pay for it, but I'd prefer not to as I really don't see the need for this small project, unless I need to). I did however pay for the email.

I've also read that Outlook doesn't support smpt: [Outlook 365 OAuth 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639809/outlook-365-oauth-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)

My settings in Django are:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '###@###.###'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '###@###.###'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '########'
```

My question is can I send Outlook emails through Django? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure SMTP authentication is enabled for your tenant. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults

Comment: Thank you so much. I began following that powershell guide before I made this post and stopped because I really had no idea what I was doing and was afraid it wasn't even right. Since you posted it I figured it must be right so persisted and got it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I called Microsoft support. They instructed me to change some security properties in Microsoft Azure. [Here is my answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63579560/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username-in-smtp-office365-com/70231003#70231003)