# OUTLOOK SMTP - Mail not sending on production using rails

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-6

I have the below configuration on my development.rb and production.rb.

```rb
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV["HOST_NAME"] }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = { from: ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"] }
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.office365.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'smtp.office365.com',
    user_name:            ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

When I try to send from the local the mail sent without any problem. but in production I get the error message.

I used the `authentication: :login` method to authenticate, but the error throws

```rb
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MW4P221CA0003.NAMP221.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM])
```

I also changed the Email settings to allow (POP and IMAP) on the settings/mail/sync mail/

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639809/outlook-365-oauth-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful

Comment: The question shows OAUTH, but im trying with login. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is most likely due to basic auth being disabled. You need to either use OAuth or enable basic auth for that mailbox or the whole tenant.